# How to disable Automatic Turn-Off at Power connection lost on Android 4.0.4 device

Tags: android, system-shutdown

I have a car mirror with build-in Android device allowing to use rearview camera, GPS and other applications and see them on a 4.3 inch screen inside the mirror.

The problem is that the Android has a setting which forces the OS to Automatically Shut-Down whenever the power supply is cut off. This is very useful feature when using in a car, but the problem is that sometimes the car may have a very short power drop in the electrical system which makes the Android start an "Automatic shutdown" and show a countdown for 10 seconds. So every 5-8 minutes I have turn it back on because of this setting.

My question is - how to disable this option?! The mirror has a small build-in battery so it can handle a short time without power supply. I want to be able to manually choose when to Turn it on and off.

The Android is version 4.0.4, the model of the mirror appears as "SoftwinnerCvr", the Kernel is "3.0.8 liyong@dx-desktop #74" and the Build number is "crane_cvr_eng 4.0.4 IMM76D". The device is rooted and has SU on it.